# Is this a better involution S-Box for the Anubis cipher?

Tags: cryptanalysis, s-boxes

After swapping random indexes of trivial involution $S[x] = ¬x$, I found the following involution S-Box with a non-linearity of $98$ and a differential uniformity of $6$.

Is there an upper limit to maximum non-linearity attainable for an involution S-Box?

For example: the Anubis cipher S-Box has a non-linearity of $96$ and a differential uniformity of $8$. Will the Anubis cipher become stronger if I use the S-Box I found?

```
byte[] S = new byte[256]
{
    0xde,0x32,0x10,0xc3,0x9e,0x52,0x89,0x6a,0xe8,0x97,0x29,0x6d,0x35,0xcb,0xb5,0xc7,
    0x02,0xc0,0xba,0x1a,0xda,0x62,0x60,0x47,0xed,0xcd,0x13,0x7b,0x88,0x4b,0x21,0x87,
    0xa1,0x1e,0x82,0x70,0xa9,0xd1,0xa3,0x79,0x30,0x0a,0xd6,0xdc,0xce,0x5e,0x6c,0xc2,
    0x28,0x64,0x01,0xa0,0xe1,0x0c,0xfa,0x42,0x48,0xc8,0x44,0x6f,0x50,0xbb,0xb6,0xbd,
    0xfd,0xc5,0x37,0xab,0x3a,0x49,0xf5,0x17,0x38,0x45,0xf6,0x1d,0x77,0xef,0xaa,0xdf,
    0x3c,0xb7,0x05,0xa8,0xac,0x8f,0x66,0xf2,0x85,0x9b,0x5d,0xe3,0x7c,0x5a,0x2d,0x69,
    0x16,0x75,0x15,0xd3,0x31,0xf7,0x56,0xc1,0x84,0x5f,0x07,0xb0,0x2e,0x0b,0xe7,0x3b,
    0x23,0x7f,0x7d,0xee,0xf3,0x61,0xe9,0x4c,0xd5,0x27,0xd0,0x1b,0x5c,0x72,0x81,0x71,
    0x83,0x7e,0x22,0x80,0x68,0x58,0xbe,0x1f,0x1c,0x06,0x8e,0x92,0xa6,0xf1,0x8a,0x55,
    0x96,0xa4,0x8b,0xec,0xd8,0xb3,0x90,0x09,0xd9,0xf0,0x9f,0x59,0xf9,0xb8,0x04,0x9a,
    0x33,0x20,0xb9,0x26,0x91,0xaf,0x8c,0xdd,0x53,0x24,0x4e,0x43,0x54,0xff,0xcf,0xa5,
    0x6b,0xe0,0xc6,0x95,0xdb,0x0e,0x3e,0x51,0x9d,0xa2,0x12,0x3d,0xd4,0x3f,0x86,0xf8,
    0x11,0x67,0x2f,0x03,0xc9,0x41,0xb2,0x0f,0x39,0xc4,0xe4,0x0d,0xeb,0x19,0x2c,0xae,
    0x7a,0x25,0xfe,0x63,0xbc,0x78,0x2a,0xea,0x94,0x98,0x14,0xb4,0x2b,0xa7,0x00,0x4f,
    0xb1,0x34,0xf4,0x5b,0xca,0xfb,0xfc,0x6e,0x08,0x76,0xd7,0xcc,0x93,0x18,0x73,0x4d,
    0x99,0x8d,0x57,0x74,0xe2,0x46,0x4a,0x65,0xbf,0x9c,0x36,0xe5,0xe6,0x40,0xd2,0xad
};
```

Comment: are you sure the nonlinearity of the Anubis s-box is 96? my test says it is 94

Comment: Should consider trying the original Anubis s-box. The current S-box is the product of 2  4-bit s-boxes, to make hardware implementations easier. Presumably the first s-box would be more secure as there is a limit to security of a random 4-bit s-box as opposed to a random 8-bit s-box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your differential uniformity and non-linearity figures are correct, then yes, your s-box is slightly stronger against basic differential and linear cryptanalysis.  Although Anubis already was essentially immune to basic differential and linear cryptanalysis.  However your s-box would need to be evaluated against other forms of cryptanalysis (e.g. interpolation, invariant subspace, etc) in order to determine if it was "better" in a more general sense.  It may also be less efficient in terms of hardware implementation than the current Anubis s-box (to invoke another, no-less crucial sense of "better").

Note: The AES s-box is affine-equivalent to an involution (as will be obvious if you think about the multiplicative inversion function), and has a higher non-linearity and lower differential uniformity.  Non-linearity and differential uniformity are the same for all affine-equivalent permutations.  So that should help address your question about the maximum non-linearity of an involution.

Comment: His figures are correct. Autocorrelation is 96, SSI is 251392, SAC and 2nd order SAC relative error is 21.9%, AVAL rel error is 4.69%, 2nd order AVAL rel error is 7.42%, BIC is 0.2288, 2nd order BIC is 0.28139

Comment: "SSI is 251392". what do you mean by SSI.

Comment: @vinu - you need to include an "@Richie Frame" at the start of your comment to ensure he sees it.

Comment: @vinu - however, I believe "SSI" means the "sum of squares indicator".  Richie Frame can correct me if I have misinterpreted him.

Comment: @vinu yes JD is correct. Out of curiosity I will get the numbers from the original s-box when I have time

Comment: For the original s-box, autocorrelation is 96, SSI is 272896, SAC and 2nd order SAC relative error is 21.9%, AVAL rel error is 3.91%, 2nd order AVAL rel error is 6.64%, BIC is 0.2549, 2nd order BIC is 0.28055, and my nonlinearity test says 94

Comment: @J.D. "Non-linearity and differential uniformity are the same for all affine-equivalent permutations" - do you have a link with more information about this and why it is the case? I have wondered about the nature of the relationship of these two stats and would like to learn more.

Comment: @EllaRose - I don't have a link, but the intuition is this - if two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are affine equivalent to each other, that means $f(x) = a(g(b(x)))$ where $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are affine functions.  In other words $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the same s-box except one is composed with some affine functions.  Differences propagate through affine functions with probability 1, so those affine functions cannot change the differential probabilities of the core 'shared' s-box.  Hence the two functions will have the same max differential probability (same uniformity).

Comment: @EllaRose - P.S. if that short explanation doesn't suffice I think the topic of how affine equivalence affects differential uniformity could make for a good question . . .

Comment: @J.D. So basically, it seems like an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) just moves or transforms some points without really modifying the structure of the points being transformed. So every point remains the same relative distance from the other points. Is this a good explanation for why differences are not modified by affine functions, or is this totally wrong and there is some other reason? Or should I just post that as a Q? Thanks!

Comment: @EllaRose - you're thinking along the right tracks, but it can't hurt to post this as a Question (assuming this hasn't been asked before).  Basically it comes down to the definition of difference and the definition of linearity - a function $f(x)$ is linear iff $f(a) \oplus f(b) = f(a \oplus b)$ for all $a, b$ and some notion of addition $\oplus$ (affine functions are similar, just with the addition of a constant term).  Think about how a linear function would affect any input pair with a difference $\Delta x$ between them using the same notion of addition . . .